# fade transition in iphone (forward and backwards)

Tags: iphone, fade, transition

I'm almost done coding my project and I have come across 1 to 2 problems with the fading. Here is what my code looks like

```
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
[animation setDuration:0.5];
[animation setType:kCATransitionFade];
[animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromRight, kCATransitionFromLeft];
[animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
```

It's telling me to set a subtype. I basically want to animate going back and going forward. I know i'm pretty close. What else am i missing from the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As near as I can tell `-setSubtype:` takes one `NSString*` argument.

The line:

```
[animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromRight, kCATransitionFromLeft];
```

should probably be either:

```
[animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromRight];
```

or:

```
[animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromLeft];
```

EDIT: You may also want to add:

```
[[myView layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"transitionFromRight"];
```

to begin animating your `myView` object (which is a `UIView` or subclass).

Comment: Awesome! So it's not asking my about the subtype anymore but now that i build and go it does not show any transitions.

Answer (score 1):

From the transitions example you can use braces instead of , notice the correct curly braces: `{` around the type and subtype instead of the brackets: `[`:

```
NSString *types[4] = {kCATransitionMoveIn, 
    kCATransitionPush, kCATransitionReveal, kCATransitionFade};
NSString *subtypes[4] = {kCATransitionFromLeft, 
    kCATransitionFromRight, kCATransitionFromTop, kCATransitionFromBottom};
```